# Problema al enviar formulario con AJAX de input name="names[]"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo un formulario que envia los datos de inputs name="nombre[]" por ajax, sin embargo, en la respuesta de la petición me señala "undifined index X".
Cabe señalar que los input están dentro de una tabla y están siendo añadidos por jquery .append();

---

```
        $(document).ready(function(){

$('#hora').click(function(){
var hour = $('input[name=hora]').val();
$('#throw').append('<th>'+hour+'</th>');
$('#lunes').append('<td><input name="lunes[]" class="input-mat" size="10" value="-" style="border-color: transparent; text-align: center;" ></td>');
$('#martes').append('<td><input name="martes[]" class="input-mat" size="10" value="-" style="border-color: transparent; text-align: center;" ></td>');
$('#miercoles').append('<td><input name="miercoles[]" class="input-mat" size="10" value="-" style="border-color: transparent; text-align: center;" ></td>');
$('#jueves').append('<td><input name="jueves[]" class="input-mat" size="10" value="-" style="border-color: transparent; text-align: center;" ></td>');
$('#viernes').append('<td><input name="viernes[]" class="input-mat" size="10" value="-" style="border-color: transparent; text-align: center;" ></td>');
$('#sabado').append('<td><input name="sabado[]" class="input-mat" size="10" value="-" style="border-color: transparent; text-align: center;" ></td>');
$('#domingo').append('<td><input name="domingo[]" class="input-mat" size="10" value="-" style="border-color: transparent; text-align: center;" ></td>');
})

$('#guardar').click(function() {
$.ajax({
url: 'http://localhost/lorem_ipsum/Horario/saveHorario',
data: $('#formulario').serialize()+'&gs=1',
type: 'post'
}).then(function(){
alert('hmmm aberla');
location.reload();
});
});
});
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puede ser que estés accediendo mal a los datos en tu backend
prueba revisar con foreach

prueba con este ejemplo:

```
foreach($_POST['lunes'] as $lunes)
{
   echo $lunes;
}
```

revisa que tu tabla este dentro del formulario con id="formulario"